# Find *all* numerical solutions to cosine based equality

Tags: equation-solving, trigonometry

To help with https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/11456/ I'm 
trying to find *all* numerical solutions to:

```
5.20427*Sin[0.529699*t] == Sin[2*Pi*t]
```

Since the period of the first function is 11.8618, I would expect to 
see 2 answers per period, or about one answer for every length 5.9309 
interval.

At first, the graphs of these functions (for 0<=t<=12):

[image]

seem to bear this out.

However, the graph for 11<=t<=13:

[image]

shows the situation can be much worse, with two "extra" nearly equal 
solutions in addition the "expected" solution.

Is there any good way to find *all* numerical solutions, including 
these "corner cases"?

Comment: `Reduce[520427/100000*Sin[529699/1000000*t] - Sin[2*Pi*t] == 0 && 
   0 <= t <= 100, t, Reals] // N` with some reasonable bound on *t* might get you what you're after...

Comment: Or, `NSolve[{5.20427*Sin[0.529699*t] == Sin[2*Pi*t] // Rationalize[#, 0] &,
   0 <= t <= 100}, t]`

Comment: Thanks, @ciao and Bob! I had considered Rationalize'ing the equations, but thought that would make things worse, not better. Bob, your solution works even without Rationalize, though Mathematica auto-rationalizes with the warning message "Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result.". If either of you would write this up as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSolve` (or `Reduce` as pointed out by @ciao in the comments above) will find all solutions in a specified interval

```
$Version
```

> "10.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (July 7, 2015)"

```
NSolve[{5.20427*Sin[0.529699*t] == Sin[2*Pi*t], 0 <= t <= 100}, t]
```

> {{t -> 0.}, {t -> 0.32491}, {t -> 5.97889}, {t -> 11.6173}, {t -> 
>      12.1353}, {t -> 12.2205}, {t -> 17.9356}, {t -> 23.5697}, {t -> 
>      29.8887}, {t -> 35.5261}, {t -> 41.1833}, {t -> 41.4872}, {t -> 
>      41.8327}, {t -> 47.4839}, {t -> 53.1234}, {t -> 53.6101}, {t -> 
>      53.7428}, {t -> 59.4409}, {t -> 65.075}, {t -> 71.3945}, {t -> 
>      77.0312}, {t -> 82.6919}, {t -> 82.9743}, {t -> 83.3401}, {t -> 
>      88.9889}, {t -> 94.6297}, {t -> 95.0909}, {t -> 95.2589}}

In some Mathematica versions there will be a warning message, e.g.,

```
$Version
```

> "10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 29, 2014)"

```
NSolve[{5.20427*Sin[0.529699*t] == Sin[2*Pi*t], 0 <= t <= 100}, t]
```

> Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact
>   coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact
>   system and numericizing the result. >>
>
> {{t -> 0.}, {t -> 0.32491}, {t -> 5.97889}, {t -> 11.6173}, {t -> 
>      12.1353}, {t -> 12.2205}, {t -> 17.9356}, {t -> 23.5697}, {t -> 
>      29.8887}, {t -> 35.5261}, {t -> 41.1833}, {t -> 41.4872}, {t -> 
>      41.8327}, {t -> 47.4839}, {t -> 53.1234}, {t -> 53.6101}, {t -> 
>      53.7428}, {t -> 59.4409}, {t -> 65.075}, {t -> 71.3945}, {t -> 
>      77.0312}, {t -> 82.6919}, {t -> 82.9743}, {t -> 83.3401}, {t -> 
>      88.9889}, {t -> 94.6297}, {t -> 95.0909}, {t -> 95.2589}}

This warning can be avoided by using `Rationalize`

```
NSolve[{5.20427*Sin[0.529699*t] == Sin[2*Pi*t] // Rationalize[#, 0] &, 
  0 <= t <= 100}, t]
```

Answer (score 1):

The package [RootSearch](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/4482/), by Ted Ersek, does what you need :

```
RootSearch[5.20427*Sin[0.529699*t] == Sin[2*Pi*t], {t, 0, 20}]
```

> {
>   {t->0.},
>   {t->0.3249099866},
>   {t->5.978887138},
>   {t->11.61730758},
>   {t->12.13526959},
>   {t->12.2204946},
>   {t->17.93561673}
>   }